# How to create a fade out effect in Tkinter? My code crashes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building an application in Tkinter with a custom window through overrideredirect. I have bound my self-designed X button to the function below. Closing the app using my button works fine, and it does fade out, but after a few seconds the window reappears, gets stuck in a loop (that's what it looks like) and crashes. It should just quit, which is what it did before I added the fadeout loop. Can someone tell me why the program reappears then crashes or offer a better alternative for a fadeout effect when closing the app (I know there are more sophisticated toolkits but I need to use Tkinter in this case)?

Thanks

```
def CloseApp(event):
if InProgress==False: #InProgress boolean defined elsewhere in program
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit","Do you really wish to quit?"):
        n=1
        while n != 0:
            n -= 0.1
            QuizWindow.attributes("-alpha", n)
            time.sleep(0.02)                                  
        Window.destroy() #I've also tried using the quit() method, not that it would make a difference
else:
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit"," If you quit now you will lose your progress and have to start again. Are you sure you want to quit?"):
        n=1
        while n != 0:
            n -= 0.1
            QuizWindow.attributes("-alpha", n)
            time.sleep(0.02)
        Window.destroy()
```

Comment: If you are able to provide any screenshots or error codes (if there are any), then it may end up being easier for people to help you out. As it can then give a better indication of what the problem may be.

Comment: There are no error codes. Saving the fuss of making a video, whilst the app is running, pressing the close button causes the window to fade out. Then 5 seconds later the window reappears and is unresponsive. Under Windows 7 it is a whiteout and on click Windows returns 'pythonw.exe is unresponsive'.

Answer (score 10):

You have two problems. First, you should never do exact comparisons to floating point numbers. Floating point math is imprecise, and `n` may never actually be `0.0000000...`.

Second, you should never call `time.sleep` in a GUI program. If you want to run something every .02 seconds, use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

Here's an example:

```python
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text="Click to fade away", command=self.quit)
        b.pack()
        self.parent = parent

    def quit(self):
        self.fade_away()

    def fade_away(self):
        alpha = self.parent.attributes("-alpha")
        if alpha > 0:
            alpha -= .1
            self.parent.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
            self.after(100, self.fade_away)
        else:
            self.parent.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain me about your code? I don't understand what self.parent.attributes("-alpha") is.

Comment: @HoseongJeon: `self.parent` is the root window. `.attributes` is a documented method of the window. `"-alpha"-` is the name of an attribute to change and `alpha` is the new value.

Comment: Perfecto! Just what I was looking for. Let's see if this is extendable to the tooltip "style" that I have in my on-going GUI development. Mr. Oakley, I notice that you are a primary respondent to Python related posts, are you the "man"?