# Make Widget Fade in/out in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python, how can I make a widget (such as text in a label) fade in, then out?

I am creating an application, and am currently developing the introduction sequence. I would like to have a series of text fade in and fade out after some time, giving the user enough time to read each portion of the full message.

Is there any way to make text and/or labels fade in and out?

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter

    class LiSA:
        def __init__(self):

            #Create the main window.
            self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

            #Designate the title of the application window.
            self.main_window.title("Whois Tool")

            #Designate the dimensions of the application window.
            self.main_window.geometry("500x400")

            #Set background color for main window.
            self.main_window.config(background="black")

            #Begin introduction
            self.intro_label = tkinter.Label(self.main_window, text="Hello")
            self.intro_label.config(fg="#2874A6",
                                    bg="black",
                                    font=("Times", 22))
            self.intro_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
            self.intro_label.after(1000, self.clear_label)


            #Enter the tkinter mainloop.
            tkinter.mainloop()

        def clear_label(self):
            print ("Clear label")
            self.intro_label.fade()

    wake_up = LiSA()
```

Comment: I do not believe `tkinter` supports fade in/out.

Comment: Correct. There are no out-of-the-box animation effects with Tkinter. You could write something yourself to gradually change the color of the font to fade to the background color and then be deleted.

Comment: you will have to use `after()` to run periodically function which will change font color to the background color.

Comment: @DYZ I suppose this is not true. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491488/how-to-create-a-fade-out-effect-in-tkinter-my-code-crashes
Perhaps not for individual widgets, but for tkinter Baselevel objects?