# How to fade in/out a label or a button in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

I am programming in PyCharm using Tkinter module and I am trying to find out, how to fade in and out a label or a button the easiest way. Is somebody here that knows how to do that

Comment: Here is an option to make the whole window fade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491488/how-to-create-a-fade-out-effect-in-tkinter-my-code-crashes

Comment: Yea but I am kinda looking into making Label and Button fade..